# Java and Database Interaction. How to use it in a clean code manner?

Tags: java, sql, xml, templates, software-design

I am searching for new ideas of how to make my life a little bit easier. I have some Java classes, that use a set of SQL templates, that are saved in a XML File. For example, i have a function that is called `getTracksForArtist(Artist artist)` and returns a list of track objects from the database. For the lookup, i have a few xml templates, that vary for sorting/grouping issues, that are loaded, when i call the related methods. In the `getTracksForArtist(Artist artist)` method I call the queryMap.getTemplate("getTracks")` wich retreives the template, that can be modified for the according method. It works, but i think it is really ugly. For one: I would like to not get the template with a String. I also would like to see, if there are templates that are never used, wich is important, as the template XML file became quite big.

I had the idea, to replace the xml file with a enum or some class representative, that has the sql stored inside and can be called by `getTemplate(GetArtists)` for example. But the problem here is, that multiline Strings are a real pain in java. There are some plugins for eclipse, that promise to solve this issue, but they do not work as needed and i do not really like to solve a design problem with a plugin.

How do you organize your java/database interaction?

Comment: Use DAO pattern and implement over an ORM approach

Comment: That is actually something i would like to do, but the (business) codebase is quite large and it would require a lot of meetings to chang this. But other than that, it would not fix the issue of long sql statements, that have to be stored somewhere.

Comment: I had implemented in the past something as the one you describe (the actual situation,  not your improvement ideas). If I had to restart,  I'd try to integrate Mybatis (http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html). Also if you don't plan to integrate it,  it might be worthwhile to take a look for their approach (disclaimer: I always preferred not to mix code and SQL so that database-savvy people could take a look and suggest improvements).

Comment: On first glance, this would be exactly what would beautify a lot of problems. There still would be no way of knowing if there is dead XML, but it is a good start. I will look into it tomorrow and see, if it meets my needs. Thanks so far!

Comment: If your queries seem really complex, you might consider adding an abstraction layer in the database by creating _database views_ that encapsulate the logic needed for querying some domain entity. These are much handier to maintain than a bunch of SQL queries in XML files -- biggest benefit being that they are precompiled (you see obvious errors compile-time vs. runtime). [Spring's JDBCTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) is one framework that helps to avoid some of the boilerplate code on the Java side.

Comment: For the "dead XML"  issue,  in my custom solution I had a simple "dashboard" with statistics for every query.  If I wanted to do that analysis,  I would have found possible candidates for deletion by comparing the total list of queries with the queries in the dashboard.  I don't know if in Mybatis it is possible to replicate this approach.

Comment: @Mick_Mnemonic the views suggestion is a good one. There's only one warning for the OP I can think of: it won't be always possible to have a "simple" query->view conversion, as to apply dynamic conditions on the view you'll have to "expose" all the information to filter as fields of the view. E.g. if your condition is in an EXISTS or IN sub query, you'll probably need to convert that condition to a join of some sort.

Comment: @MickMnemonic thanks for the idea, but we are allready using some views. It is just, that we have a lot of different sorting/grouping Querys, that all vary a little bit, so we still have a lot of querys to maintain. I did not get around to try the mybatis, but hopefully can post some feedback soon.